# Pattern matching in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, regular-expression

I have a string in which need to extract the date,

Example: S01_XXX001_000_min_01_**20150526**T**123440583**.arc ,
S01_XXX001_000_**20150526**T**123440583**_min_01.arc

based on the pattern like '**Numeric T Numeric**',

I am trying to extract with the below sql , can any one help me.

SQL:

```
select  substring('S01_ZAR001_000_min_01_20150526T123440583.arc','^\d')

select  substring('SAPCC_XX_ZZZ_BitClass_XXX_20150623T45656566456_XXX_XX_XXXXXX.arc' like '_%T%_',1,8)

select  substring('SAPCC_XX_ZZZ_BitClass_XXX_201506235T335656_XXX_XX_XXXXXX.arc','[^_]+([^0-9]{1,8})$')

SELECT SUBSTRING('XY1234Z', 'Y*([0-9]{1,3})');
```

Comment: Why the `mysql` and `oracle` tags?

Comment: pattern matching is mostly similar , Just looking for some hope

Comment: No it's not "*mostly similar*". The syntax is completely different between those three DBMS.

Comment: Isn't the part after the 'T' the time?  From your examples it looks like it isn't - in this case, you just want to discard it?

Comment: One more: `201506235` is not a valid date in you third example.

Comment: You'll have to give us the input_string and your desired result. Showing us what you've tried would also be good. Voting to close until clarification is forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select substr(
        substring('SAPCC_XX_ZZZ_Bit1T1Class_XXX_201506235T335656_XXX_XX_XXXXXX'
                  from 
                  '_[0-9]+T[0-9]+_'
                 ), 2, 8
             )::date
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain this a bit?

Comment: needs explaining

Comment: extracting the data from the file (i.e 2015-06-23)